RESTEASY003190: Could not find constructor for class
I'm trying setup a very basic tomcat 10+Resteasy 6.2.8.Final+CDI (weld 5.1.2.Final) (the latest as I'm writing)
The documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/6.2.8.Final/userguide/html_single/#standalone_resteasy
But when running:
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003190: Could not find constructor for class: com.cdi.GreetingResource
my code: https://github.com/brunorozendo/jakarta-ee-10/tree/main/cdi
package com.cdi;


import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/greet")
public class GreetingResource {

    private final GreetingService greetingService;

    @Inject
    public GreetingResource(GreetingService greetingService) {
        this.greetingService = greetingService;
    }

    @GET
    public String get() {
        greetingService.setName("bruno");
        greetingService.createMessage();
        return greetingService.getMessage();
    }
}

package com.cdi;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@RequestScoped
public class GreetingService {

    private String name;
    private String message;

    public void createMessage() {
        message = "Hello, " + getName() + "!";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}


It’s somewhat of a bug with RESTEasy, but you need to have a no-arg constructor. It just inject the GreeterService via the instance.

@JamesR.Perkins I update the question, I was already using @inject in a constructor

Right, what I meant was something like @Inject private GreetingService greetingService. The construction injection on resources doesn’t always work.
